# how to redraw a line on a line which is already drawn in tkinter canvas smoothly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have some `lines` in tinter canvas, and also have their code. I want to make them red but not at a same time I want to draw another line(red line) go on them but it should take different time. for example fo one specific line it should take 3 seconds that line get red for another one it should take 7 seconds to make that red. it is like drawing another red line on the previous one.

```
def activator(self, hexagon, duration_time):
    if not hexagon.is_end:

        self.canvas.itemconfigure(hexagon.drawn, fill="tomato")
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(hexagon.hex_aspects.outputs.drawn, fill="tomato")
```

for example I want my hexagon which created by createpolygon method of tinter get red but not immediately. It should do regarding to duration_time which is the a second variable. I mean it should be done within duration_time second(let say 3 second). is there any way for doing this? I have lots of object in my canvas which should get red during an specific time. line, circle, polygon..

Answer (score 1):

A line on a `tk.canvas` is defined by a `start` and an `end` point; in order to access points on the line, we need to first create an affine line by first generating many points at an interval on the line, then join them with line segments.

This affine line is created upon clicking on an item on the canvas, but is hidden at first, and progressively revealed over a short time interval.

Once the redraw is completed, the affine line is hidden again, and the item being redrawn set to its new color.

This "simple" redraw requires quite a bit of machinery to implement. You can try it by clicking on a line to redraw it, and see the animation of the redraw.

**Code:**

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500


class AffinePoint:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return AffinePoint(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return AffinePoint(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return AffinePoint(self.x * scalar, self.y * scalar)

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y

    def draw(self, canvas):
        offset = AffinePoint(2, 2)
        return canvas.create_oval(*(self + offset), *self - offset, fill='', outline='black')


def create_affine_points(canvas, num_points):
    """sanity check"""
    for _ in range(num_points):
        AffinePoint(random.randrange(0, WIDTH), random.randrange(0, HEIGHT)).draw(canvas)


class AffineLineSegment:

    def __init__(self, start, end, num_t=100):
        self.start = AffinePoint(*start)
        self.end = AffinePoint(*end)
        self.num_t = num_t
        self.points = []
        self._make_points()
        self.segments = []

    def _make_points(self):
        for _t in range(self.num_t):
            t = _t / self.num_t
            self.points.append(self.start + (self.end - self.start) * t)

    def __iter__(self):
        for point in self.points:
            yield point

    def draw(self, canvas):
        for p0, p1 in zip(self.points[:-1], self.points[1:]):
            self.segments.append(canvas.create_line(*p0, *p1, width=5, state='hidden', fill='red'))

    def hide(self, canvas):
        for seg in self.segments:
            canvas.itemconfigure(seg, state='hidden')


def create_affine_line(canvas, num_lines):
    """sanity check"""
    for _ in range(num_lines):
        start = random.randrange(0, WIDTH), random.randrange(0, HEIGHT)
        end = random.randrange(0, WIDTH), random.randrange(0, HEIGHT)
        AffineLineSegment(start, end).draw(canvas)


def select_and_redraw(event):
    item = canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(item)
    canvas.itemconfigure(item, fill='grey25')
    canvas.itemconfigure(item, width=1)
    a = AffineLineSegment((x0, y0), (x1, y1))
    a.draw(canvas)
    gen = (segment for segment in a.segments)
    redraw(gen, a, item)


def redraw(gen, a, item):
    try:
        segment = next(gen)
        canvas.itemconfigure(segment, state='normal')
        root.after(10, redraw, gen, a, item)
    except StopIteration:
        a.hide(canvas)
        canvas.itemconfigure(item, state='normal')
        canvas.itemconfigure(item, fill='red')
        canvas.itemconfigure(item, width=3)
    finally:
        root.after_cancel(redraw)


root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="cyan")
canvas.pack()

canvas.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', select_and_redraw)

# sanity checks
# create_affine_points(canvas, 500)
# create_affine_line(canvas, 100)

for _ in range(10):
    start = random.randrange(0, WIDTH), random.randrange(0, HEIGHT)
    end = random.randrange(0, WIDTH), random.randrange(0, HEIGHT)    
    canvas.create_line(*start, * end, activefill='blue', fill='black', width=3)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Screen capture showing a line in the process of being redrawn

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np

root = Tk()


def lighter(color, percent):
    color = np.array(color)
    white = np.array([255, 255, 255])
    vector = white-color
    return tuple(color + vector * percent)


def Fade(line, start_rgb, percentage, times, delay):
    '''assumes color is rgb between (0, 0, 0) and (255, 255, 255) adn percentage a value between 0.0 and 1.0'''
    new_color = lighter(start_rgb, percentage)
    red, blue, green = new_color
    red = int(red)
    blue = int(blue)
    green = int(green)
    new_hex = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (red, blue, green)

    canvas.itemconfigure(line, fill=new_hex)
    if times > 0:
        root.after(delay, lambda: Fade(line, new_color, percentage, times - 1, delay))


canvas = Canvas(root, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

line = canvas.create_line(0, 0, 100, 100, width=10)
Fade(line, (0, 0, 50), 0.01, 1000, 10)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: it does, what exactly it designed for, I mean it draw a line and after some given seconds makes it red. but I want it to get red  during this given second. I user should see that the drawing is going on.

Comment: maybe now is better

Comment: sorry but it's not something that it supposed to do, your code make the whole line bright in a given second while it should start to make the line bright from the beginning of the line to the end of the line during that given sec. it should be like drawing another line over the current line with a different colour(during given sec).